# Capture flash/no-flash images quickly using Android Camera2 API

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2

I am writing an android application to capture flash/no-flash image pair quickly when a user presses capture button. For writing my application I referred to Camera2Basic app [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.java).

From Android documentation, I found that for flash to fire, the preview request builder should have **AE_MODE** set to **AE_MODE_ON_ALWAYS_FLASH**.

I am using three request builders: **preview**, **noflash** and **flash**
The difference between three is:

- **preview**: AE_MODE set to AE_MODE_ON_ALWAYS_FLASH and AF_MODE set to CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE
- **noflash**: AE_MODE set to AE_MODE_ON
- **flash**: AE_MODE set to AE_MODE_ONALWAYS_FLASH

I am using **Nexus 5** device and I found that for capturing just a flash image, one must have preview builder and flash builder as described above, and submit a still capture request using above **flash** builder. Using this sequence, I ***always*** get a proper flash image in Nexus 5. The pre-flash is ***always*** automatically handled.

Coming to original question, capturing a pair of flash/no-flash images, my sequence of steps is as follows:

1. In take picture, I start auto-focus trigger using **preview** builder.
2. When auto-focus is complete, I submit two still capture requests back to back using **noflash** and **flash** builders (***first noflash, then flash***)

However, the ***first*** image I get is a ***flash image*** and ***second*** is a ***no-flash image***. I don't understand this reversal in output.

1. **JPEG case:** **First** image is ***always*** a ***proper flash image***, **second** image is ***always*** a ***proper no-flash image*** as shown below:

Flash image corresponding to request submitted using **noflash** builder:
[image]

No-flash image corresponding to request submitted using **flash** builder:
[image]

2. **YUV_420_888 case:** Sames as in JPEG, however, ***noflash image is never proper***. One can notice a ***white strip*** on right side as well as improper colors, also it is very ***noisy***!

Flash image corresponding to request submitted using **noflash** builder:
[image]

***Improper no-flash*** image corresponding to request submitted using **flash** builder:
[image]

Off-course, since in YUV_420_888 format two images are captured back to back, I add a **preview** request in between to prevent spill over.

My questions are:

1. Why the order of output images is reversed?
2. Why no-flash image in YUV_420_888 format is not proper?

Please help.

Comment: I am afraid that each device will behave a bit different in this scenario. Don't expect any one-serves-all sequence, and remember that even today many devices only have partial support for camera2 API.

Comment: @AlexCohn: I think you are right. I tested on Galaxy S6 and the flash fires only once, the flash image is over-exposed. However, there must be a proper sequence for capturing flash images in these devices
 too.

Comment: `AE_MODE_ON_ALWAYS_FLASH` not working on Galaxy S6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To confirm a few things:

1. Make sure the triggers are only set to START for a single request, not continuously
2. If the AE_MODE is one of the ones where AE controls flash, FLASH_MODE is ignored; best not to touch it just in case anyway.
3. Make sure to use the STILL_CAPTURE request template for the final capture request; otherwise main flash is not expected to fire.
4. You should be able to submit a second no-flash STILL_CAPTURE request almost right after the flash request (to be safe, leave one request of buffer, since due to rolling shutter, the main flash may partially be visible one frame before and after the flash capture); just submit a preview request and then a STILL_CAPTURE request with AE_MODE_ON.
5. For maximum speed, do not capture JPEG images; the extra encoding time can cause delays between the images.  Use YUV_420_888 and create JPEGs yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help! I have managed to properly capture no-flash and flash images on Nexus 5. I am capturing in YUV_420_888 format as you suggested. I am using 2 capture builders and submitting 2 requests (no-flash, then flash) almost at same time. I get the no-flash image capture callback after ~200 ms and flash image callback after ~350 ms (2 different capture callbacks). So, the flash image is captured after ~150 ms of capturing no-flash image. Do you see any further scope of improvisation?

Comment: Why not submit them in a burst together, with captureBurst (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCaptureSession.html#captureBurst(java.util.List<android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest>, android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback, android.os.Handler) )?  Make the flash one the first one, and add one preview request in the middle as a guard against flash spillover.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I tried this, but still there is same delay of 150 ms! Just to confirm, I'm using SystemClock.uptimeMillis() to get the time in millisecond inside the capture callback. So, when I get callback of flash image I get T1 time in ms; next when I get callback of no-flash image I get T2 time in ms. So, am I correct in saying that no-flash image was CAPTURED after T2-T1 ms of capturing flash image?

Comment: Also, when I say that I want to quickly capture a pair of flash/no-flash images, I mean that the images are captured very fast by the camera sensor and image registration/alignment is not required. So, if measure the time as I have explained above in case of YUV format, does 150 ms signify that (CAPTURE) delay by sensor? Thank you.

Comment: The capture result contains the timestamp for start of exposure (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureResult.html#SENSOR_TIMESTAMP), so that's the most accurate times you can compare.  There are assorted delays through the system, so comparing the time in the capture callback isn't going to be as accurate, especially if the no-flash shot needs a long exposure.

Comment: You can take a look at the reported exposure time as well (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureResult.html#SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME), in case the flash photo or the single preview capture have a long enough exposure time that it's delaying the no-flash shot.

Comment: Thanks! As you said, I used SENSOR_TIMESTAMP for comparing the delay between two images. To measure the delay, I just subtract the flash image timestamp T2 from no-flash image timestamp T1. However, for JPEG format I get ~300 ms and for YUV_420_888 format ~75 ms. It seems, the SENSOR_TIMESTAMP values gets changed while reprocessing. I tried to figure out from official doc: "For reprocessing, the timestamp will match the start of exposure of the input image, i.e. the timestamp in the TotalCaptureResult that was used to create the reprocess capture request.", but it is not clear to me.

Comment: Further, if this is the case, then whether I set the format as YUV_420_888 or JPEG, the actual sensor delay between the two images must always be ~75 ms. Am I right?

Comment: No - the second JPEG image can't start capturing until the first is done compressing (there's only one JPEG compressor, and there's no input queue to it), so that delay is a real one.  Use YUV_420_888 for burst captures, precisely because of this.

Comment: Oh! Thanks a lot. By the way, while using captureBurst() and YUV_420_888 format, if the order of images is Flash->No-flash, then the flash image is coming half black. If order is No-flash->Flash, everything is proper. In both cases, I am adding a preview request in the middle.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I didn't pay attention to points 1 and 2 in your answer and now I have run into a problem. Can you please read my updated question above, I've added my final images as well. According to point 2 in your answer I infer that I should not touch FLASH_MODE, am I right? And regarding trigger (point 1), I am using only AF trigger with preview builder. Request you to please read my updated question above. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @EddyTalvala  `AE_MODE_ON_ALWAYS_FLASH` not working on Galaxy S6